# Two dimensional conformal field theories with changing central charge

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, topological-field-theory

For two-dimensional conformal field theories it is usually assumed that the cental charge is fixed (for simplicity let's assume that $c=\bar c$).

Is there a generalization or a concept that uses the concept of changing central charge within one theory? Is there any useful interpretation for this scenario?

Comment: It is possible to define the so-called $C$-function in the renormalization group (RG) flow of a theory from one CFT to another. This $C$ function is equal to the central charge of the CFTs located at the beginning and end of the RG flow. Interestingly, this function is monotonically decreasing, implying that the central charge can only ever decrease as one flows from one CFT to another. For more info, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-theorem